# Detect Heap Corruption only no developement computer

Tags: visual-c++, heap-corruption

I use VS 2012 for write an MFC application in C++
In my computer I have no problem but when I lauch in other computer I have heap corruption detected problem.
Do you have some idea how I could solve it knowledge that the error does not produce in my computer so I could not lauch debugger to access my code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the remote debugging feature of VS. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t(v=vs.110).aspx

Normaly this kind of bug arises from not init member variables.